# Yealink T46S fails to apply non-MAC specific configs while provisioning

Tags: provisioning

I am deploying some 50 of SIP-T46S phones, and got stuck with really weird behavior.

According to Yealink manuals, "new" provisioning process is getting .boot file and applying configs in order specified in there.

I decided to go this way:
y000000000000000.boot -> common.cfg -> mac-specific.cfg

y000000000000000.boot contains this:

```
[T46S]include:config <T46S/$MAC.cfg>
include:config <common.cfg>

overwrite_mode = 1
specific_model.excluded_mode=0
```

Now I can read from TFTP logs that phones **successfully download both .cfgs**, but for some reason doesn't apply settings from common.cfg. Settings from $MAC.cfg are applied successfully.

Switching lines doesn't help. When I move lines from common.cfg to $MAC.cfg, they are applied.

Firmware Version    66.84.0.15
Hardware Version    66.0.0.128.0.0.0

The question is: why non mac-specific config is dropped?

Please help to understand and solve the problem.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour was a missing header in the common.cfg:

```
#!version:1.0.0.1
```

This header is **mandatory** for all Yealink config files.

Also I noted that if admin password is specified in 1st line, it seem to be dropped. So I needed to specify another parameter first.